# How to create a n-bit counter using GAL, programming in WinCUPL

Tags: hardware, hdl

No, I need the shortest possible solution, preferably with macro folding.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I did this, cascading Repeat macros:

```
Name     8-bit counter ;
PartNo   MIC20181 ;
Date     2015/2/8 ;
Revision 01 ;
Designer Engineer ;
Company  Donghua University ;
Assembly None ;
Location  ;
Device   g16v8 ;

/* Input pins */

Pin 1 = CLK;
Pin 11 = GND;

/* Output pins */

PinNode [12..19] = [Q7..0];

Append Q0.D = !Q0;

Append Q1.D = !Q1 & Q0;
Append Q1.D = Q0 & !Q1;

$Repeat P = [2..7]
$Repeat R = [{P - 1}..0]
Append Q{P}.D = Q{P} & !Q{R};
$RepEnd
Append Q{P}.D = !Q{P} & !([Q{P-1}..0]:#);
$RepEnd
```

The trick here is how I (ab)used `$Repeat` macros.